# How to create a Key wording/tagging system that works across editing platforms

Tags: video-editor

I am an intern with the creative team at a large service organization that works around the world.  We have a large amount of footage from years and years of shooting.  I have been brought on to come up with and implement a key wording/tagging system to make finding clips easier. The goal is to make a keyword/tagging system that is future proof.  Meaning the tags will work across platforms in the case that the organization switches editing softwares.  Final Cut X is able to use keywords/tags that are generated in finder.  However Premiere is unable to read these as far as I can tell.  Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?  The other thing I have tried is generating keywords in Prelude and then seeing if those transfer over to Final Cut.  They do not either.  Any ideas on making a system that can work across platforms would be great!

Thanks!

Christian

Comment: I would start look at more of an asset management solution Apple used to have Final Cut Server but there are other systems that are similar made by many others, so might be worth starting there and working forward

Comment: Seconding that you want to look into asset management solutions. If you are not primarily a media organization, then you can use either digital asset management (assuming they specify that they can handle video) or media asset management products. If you are primarily a media organization, look into MAM solutions specifically. It is tough to recommend something specific without knowing a lot more details, especially budget.

Comment: I essentially need something that can help me tag media and then search for that media based on the tags I make.  On the simplest level that is all it needs to do.